# Is there any way to get public event informations from Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I know since Cambridge Analytica facebook API has suspended some endpoints. But I need facebook public events informations for a project. The informations I need are:

- Event Name
- Date and Time
- Cover photo
- Description
- Event URL
- Address
- Event ID
- Page ID

I'm doing a project for a client. It will request those data from server side and save it in database. Then it will show available events in a community website for specific locations. We don't need data about attendee list or their post on the wall. My client is willing to go through app review process. Question is does Facebook sdk provide those informations? Reading the documentation, my understanding is it only provide event informations that are attended by me or created in a page in which I'm an admin.

Is there any way to get these information? Let me be clear, I'm talking about public events. Not the one created by me or by my page.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: please add what you have tried so far (research, code, debug info, ...)

Comment: I'm doing a project for a client. It will request those data from server side and save it in database. Then it will show available events in a community website for specific locations. We don't need data about attendee list or their post on the wall. My client is willing to go through app review process. Question is does Facebook sdk provide those informations? Reading the documentation, my understanding is it only provide event informations that are attended by me or created in a page in which I'm an admin. If they do provide, can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The solutions I have found are all backdated and isn't relevant now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be 100% sure, I just tried to access events of a Page I don´t own, with a live App that has Page Public Content Access approved, and did not get the events. (Tested with the `/page-id/events` endpoint.)

**The docs tell you that accessing Page events is not possible in any case:**

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This confuses me - why would they limit access to public information?   It's not protecting anyone's privacy.

Comment: public on the internet does not automatically mean that you can use the data as you like - but either way, you would have to ask facebook about their restrictions :)